# `data.table` error: "reorder received irregular lengthed list" in setkey

Tags: r, data.table

I have a fairly basic `data.table` in R, with 250k rows and 90 columns. I am trying to key the `data.table` on one of the columns which is of class `character`. When I call:

```
setkey(my.dt,my.column)
```

I receive the following cryptic error message:

```
"Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose=verbose) :
reorder received irregular lengthed list"
```

I have found a [source-code commit with this message](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-commits/2011-November/000377.html), but can't quite decipher what it means. My key column contains no NA or blank values, seems perfectly reasonable to look at (it contains stock tickers), and behaves well with the default `order()` command.

Even more frustrating, the following code completes correctly:

```
first.dt <- my.dt[1:100000]
setkey(first.dt,my.column)
second.dt <- my.dt[100001:nrow(my.dt]
setkey(second.dt,my.column)
```

I have no idea what could be going on here. Any tips?

Edit 1: I have confirmed every value in the key fits a fairly standard format:

```
> length(grep("[A-Z]{3,4}\\.[A-Z]{2}",my.dt$my.column)) == nrow(my.dt)
[1] TRUE
```

Edit 2: My system info is below (note that I'm actually using Windows 7). I am using data.table version 1.8.

```
> Sys.info()
          sysname           release           version          nodename           machine             login 
        "Windows" "Server 2008 x64"      "build 7600" "WIN-9RH28AH0CKG"          "x86-64"   "Administrator" 
             user    effective_user 
  "Administrator"   "Administrator"
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert your column to a `factor`?

Comment: Just tried it, the conversion went fine but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Ok. Could you perhaps provide the first 10 lines of the data.table?

Comment: As mentioned, the first 10 lines will key fine. The first 100000 lines key fine. The other 150000 lines key fine. Somehow, the whole thing fails. The first 10 lines for the key column follow, I can't find any lines that don't fit this format: `"CFP.TO" "MCP.AX" "NEC.OL" "LND.PS" "MYRS.KL" "RHBC.KL" "BGRO.KL" "PBT.AX" "MEG.PS" "NOVN.VX"`

Comment: Not seen this one before. When you extract the first 100000 lines (or whatever) you're making a new object. So possibly something is corrupted in the original, somehow. Need the output of `.Internal(inspect(my.dt))` please.

Comment: Also, there are 22 bug fixes in 1.8.1 on R-Forge. Are you using 1.8.0 on CRAN? Although none of them seem related to the problem here, one of them might have bitten earlier and then manifests itself at the point of setkey in your case. So you could try upgrading to the R-Forge repo version to see if it solves it. You can always go back to 1.8.0 if need be.

Comment: Although, there is an issue with the Windows build (only) of data.table on R-Forge related to an upstream fix in R itself not yet making into the version of R that R-Forge uses to build binary packages for Windows. So if you do upgrade to 1.8.1, since you are on Windows, you'll need to build from source using Rtools or winbuilder otherwise you'll get an error about .Internal taking 6 not 7 arguments.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewDowle - I have dumped the info from `.Internal(inspect(my.dt))` here: http://pastebin.com/k9Lu2QpM

Comment: Hi Ina. Sorry to nudge you, but if that was it could you confirm by voting and accepting? I'm preparing to release 1.8.1 to CRAN soon so if you have found a new bug then I'd like to fix it in this release. Or does 1.8.1 already fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, as soon as I got it working I got lost in the actual task I was trying to achieve and neglected SO! :) Either 1.8.1 fixed it, or my object is no longer subject to the strange corruption that occurred beforehand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run :

```
sapply(my.dt, length)
```

I suspect that one or more columns have a different length to the first column, and that's an invalid `data.table`. It won't be one of the first 5 because your `.Internal(inspect(my.dt))` (thanks) shows those and they're ok.

If so, there is this bug fix in v1.8.1 :

> o   rbind() of DT with an irregular list() now recycles the list items
>       correctly, #2003. Test added.

Any chance there's an `rbind()` at an earlier point to create `my.dt` together with an irregular lengthed `list`?  If not, please step through your code running the `sapply(my.dt,length)` to see where the invalidly lengthed column is being created. Armed with that we can make a work around and also fix the potential bug.  Thanks.

EDIT :

The original cryptic error message is now improved in v1.8.1, as follows :

```
DT = list(a=6:1,b=4:1)
setattr(DT,"class",c("data.table","data.frame"))
setkey(DT,a)

Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : 
  Column 2 is length 4 which differs from length of column 1 (6). Invalid
  data.table. Check NEWS link at top of ?data.table for latest bug fixes. If
  not already reported and fixed, please report to datatable-help.
```

NB: This method to create a `data.table` is not recommended because it lets you create an invalid `data.table`. Unless, you are really sure the `list` is regular and you really do need speed (i.e. for speed you want to avoid the checks that `as.data.table()` and `data.table()` do), or you need to demonstrate an invalid `data.table`, as I'm doing here.